# Evaluate $f(x)=(1−\cos(x))/x$ for arguments $0<x≪1$

Tags: numerical-methods, error-function, condition-number

How would one usefully evaluate the function $f(x)=\frac{1-\cos (x)}{x}$  for arguments $0<x \ll 1$ evaluate? Calculate $f\left(10^{-4}\right)$ with an error smaller than $10^{-10}$.

Unfortunately, I have not yet had much to do with the field of numerics. What is clear to me is this:
$$\kappa_{f}(x)=\left|\frac{x f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)}\right|=\frac{\left(\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)^{\prime} \cdot x}{\frac{1-\cos x}{x}}$$ However, I do not know how to interpret this for the given area $0<x \ll 1$ and how I then carry out this error calculation.

Comment: By Taylor's formula,
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{24}+O(x^5)$$
as $x\to 0$. You can always keep more terms for better accuracy. Does this work?

Comment: maybe try trig identity $1-\cos(2t) = 2 \sin^2(t)$ to avoid the problematic cancellation of $1-(1-\epsilon)$ near 0

Comment: Or use $(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)=\sin^2x$. Usually the sine is implemented in such a way that $\sin(x)/x$ has no problems for small $x\ne 0$.

Comment: Do not forget that it is an alternating series if Taylor expanded

Comment: I'm not really getting anywhere yet (theoretically, the topic would be clear to me). According to Taylor, if f is twice continuously divisible, then $ \Delta y_{i}=f_{i}(x+\Delta x)-f_{i}(x)=\sum \limits_{j=0}^{m} \frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}(x) \Delta x_{j}+\mathcal{O}\left(|\Delta x|^{2}\right)$. Neglecting the residual term, the relative error in the results holds: $\frac{\Delta y_{i}}{y_{i}} \approx \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}(x) \frac{x_{j}}{f_{i}(x)} \cdot \frac{\Delta x_{j}}{x_{j}}$

Comment: Thus the numbers $k_{i j}:=\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}(x) \frac{x_{j}}{f_{i}(x)}$ a measure of the effect of the relative error in the input data on the relative error in the output data.
the output data. The funktion f(x)=(1−cos(x))/x
 would I now like to evaluate for arguments 0<x≪1.

Comment: **Without** doing the calculation, we can prove that adding $85$ terms, will give a result for an accuracy better than $10^{\color{red}{-1000}}$